# Calling docker-compose with python subprocess ends with FileNotFoundError 'docker-compose'

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, subprocess

I am quite new to docker so I ran into some error state with my python script. It should listen for a couple of docker containers which have been started with **docker-compose up** using a specific yaml file.

The ignition process is working but when one container goes down another one (observing entity) should revive it with, say **docker-compose start deadmodule**

My setup:

- OS: Windows 10
- Docker: 2.0.0.0-win78 (28905)
- Docker Engine: 18.09.0
- Compose: 1.23.1
- Python 3.6

I am trying this:

```
subprocess.call('docker-compose',
                'start',
                'deadmodule')
```

And I tried it also with `Popen(['docker-compose', 'start', 'deadmodule'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)`

However it ends with this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker-compose': 'docker-compose'
```

Comment: Is it on the PATH? Have you tried `docker-compose.exe` instead?

Comment: It is on the PATH, since I can call it manually on the windows console without any problems.

Comment: why don't just use `restart=always` in the compose file to revive it automatically with docker?

Comment: I do when I encounter any python errors they (containers) do not always come up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are not using `shell=True`, the file ending won't be automatically added, so what you need to call is `docker-compose.exe`, not `docker-compose`.